# Flutter CheckBox

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a new Flutter programmer, and I want to know how I can use a CheckBox on my App. The CheckBox doesn't need to return anything, is only a way to the user know the ingredients that they have picked up.

Thanks for everything.

Comment: [Did you check the reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html)?

Answer (score 1):

A sample below might help :

```
bool _afternoonOutdoor = false;
String caption_afternoon_outdoor = 'Afternoon Outdoor';

void _afternoonOutdoorChanged(bool value) => setState(() => _afternoonOutdoor = value);

.
.
.

Widget checkBoxTitleAfternoonOutdoor() {
        return Container(
            width:230,
         child: new CheckboxListTile(
            value: _afternoonOutdoor,
            onChanged: _afternoonOutdoorChanged,
            //title: new Text('Afternoon Outdoor'),
            //title: new Text('${_remoteConfig.getString('caption_afternoon_outdoor')}'),
            title: new Text(caption_afternoon_outdoor),
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            activeColor: Colors.blue));
      }
```

This produces the following result :

[image]

Comment: I used the Stateful too, but the code error say "The argument type 'List<String> can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. This is my code, and the List of ingredientes is on another class.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Models/meal.dart';

class Checkbox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckboxState createState() => _CheckboxState();
}

class _CheckboxState extends State<Checkbox> {
  bool isCheck = false;
  List<Meal> meal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      children: meal
          .map(
            (meal) => CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(meal.ingredientes),
              value: isCheck,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  isCheck = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```